# Spacing between table rows in Dreamweaver mail template

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I tried some solutions I found in other posts but still no luck. I'm getting a small
spacing between all my table rows. All CSS and HTML seems in order. Any ideas?

```
table {
    border-spacing: 0 !important;
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
    table-layout: fixed !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;


<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%" bgcolor="#e0e0e0" 
style="border-collapse:collapse;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change **border-collapse:collapse;** to **border-collapse:separate;** into your **table tag** inline style.

And use the below CSS code.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" style="border-collapse:separate; margin:0 auto;" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <th>Heading 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>value 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Value 3</td>
    <td>value 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Value 5</td>
    <td>value 6</td>
</tr>
</table>
```